# P2P Connect iOS Devices Securely?

Tags: ios, security, mobile, ssl-certificate, p2p

I am trying to connect iOS devices over P2P connections and I would like to do it securely. The obvious solution (as it so often is with encryption) is to wrap my connections in SSL/TLS. However, it's impossible for either device to have a trusted SSL certificate, because SSL certificates are IP address specific. **Given that certificates cannot be involved, how may I secure a P2P connection between iOS (or any mobile) devices?**

Comment: What do you mean by "securely"?  TLS provides two main functions; transport encryption and end-point identity validation/trust. Without a third-party to validate identities and issue certificates neither of these make much sense. You could embed encryption keys in your app, but this makes it reasonably easy for an attacker to recover the keys and intercept your traffic. You could also negotiate session keys but again without trusted identities this negotiation is going to happen in the clear

Comment: @Paulw11 Well I could send them each a long, random string by HTTPS from my server. They could use that to verify identity. But I've never implemented encryption myself I don't know what to do once I leave SSL/TLS.

Comment: Right, so you could have a certificate on your server and you can use that so that your app can establish trust with the server and the server could be involved in negotiating the session keys for use between the clients, but if the server can't establish trust of the client then how does it know it isn't negotiating a session key with a "bad guy". It comes back to my original question - what are you trying to achieve?  You can encrypt the traffic between peers to hide the data from a casual observer but securing against a determined attacker is a different thing.

Comment: @Paulw11 This is a good point. I want my program to be secure against even a determined attacker. I will look into device-certificate/udid pairs and that sort of thing. Thank you. If this had been an answer I would have up-voted it.